# Computing Unemployment duration (Stata)

Tags: stata

I have a panel survey that tracks the same workers with the latest year being 2019. I am interested in creating variables that capture the duration of no work for each individual, by taking the difference in years between the variables "left_firstjob_yr" and "start_secondjob_yr", which I did generate with:

```
gen no_work_duration_1 = (start_secondjob_yr  - left_firstjob_yr)
```

where "no_work_duration_1" refers to the duration of no work between the date an individual left their first job and the date where they started their second job.

However, one problem with my approach above is that it does not take into account workers who left their first job, but never worked again/left the workforce with missing "." values under the "start_secondjob_yr" column.

```
input int(start_firstjob_yr left_firstjob_yr start_secondjob_yr left_secondjob_yr) 
2014 2015 2017 2019  
2014    .    .    .    
2011 2014    .    .    
2003 2008 2011    .    
2007 2009 2012 2014
```

Ideally, I am trying to have my dataset looking as follows:

```
clear
input int(start_firstjob_yr left_firstjob_yr) byte no_work_duration_1 int(start_secondjob_yr left_secondjob_yr) byte no_work_duration_2
2014 2015 2 2017 2019 .
2014    . .    .    . .
2011 2014 5    .    . .
2003 2008 3 2011    . .
2007 2009 3 2012 2014 2
```

Comment: If `no_work_duration_1` is time between first and second job,  doesn't it makes sense that their `no_work_duration_1` is set to missing for workers who never worked a second job?

Comment: Mind elaborating more?
This is how I am measuring no_work_duration_1 = (start_secondjob_yr  - left_firstjob_yr) However, I am also trying to take into account individuals who left their first job but never worked again.

Comment: If they never work again, then their time between jobs is infinite, right?

Comment: Alternatively, for this group of workers without a second job, you could consider the `no_work_duration` to be the time between ending their last job and the current date. It all depends on what you're trying to define.

Comment: Oh got it, but no it won't be infinite. As I will consider 2019 the latest year, which the last year measured in the survey. For instance, if someone left their first job in 2012, then their no work duration would be essentially 2019- 2012... but this is the code I am struggling with.

Comment: Right, I understand now. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been clarified that for workers with no second job, that the duration
of `no_work_duration` should be the difference between leaving their first job
and 2019 (see comments on original question).

I have taken the liberty of using some shorter variable names.

```
clear

input int(j1_start j1_end j2_start j2_end) 
2014 2015 2017 2019  
2014    .    .    .    
2011 2014    .    .    
2003 2008 2011    .    
2007 2009 2012 2014
end

* No Work Duration ("nwd")
gen nwd = j2_start - j1_end

* In cases of no second job:
replace nwd = 2019 - j1_end if missing(j2_start)

list

     +---------------------------------------------+
     | j1_start   j1_end   j2_start   j2_end   nwd |
     |---------------------------------------------|
  1. |     2014     2015       2017     2019     2 |
  2. |     2014        .          .        .     . |
  3. |     2011     2014          .        .     5 |
  4. |     2003     2008       2011        .     3 |
  5. |     2007     2009       2012     2014     3 |
     +---------------------------------------------+
```